# PyQt5 proceeding to another layout in the same window

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm currently a beginner and I'm trying to make a GUI. However I have been searching everywhere for more than 3-4 days and I couldn't find the right answer that works. What I'm trying to do is that after I click the button "start" it should change the window to the second_layout window but it doesn't work. I hope that this will help others too! Thank you very much!

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QInputDialog, QStackedLayout
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Plant those trees")
        self.first_layout()

        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.layout_1)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def first_layout(self):
        self.layout_1 = QWidget()

        #image
        self.image = QLabel(self.layout_1)
        self.image.setGeometry(QRect(0, -10, 781, 381))
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap("3957f79ab9264dc.jpg"))

        #label
        self.label = QLabel(self.layout_1)
        self.label.setText("Plant those trees")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(180, 10, 591, 241))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Script")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;")

        #push button 1
        self.pushbutton1 = QPushButton(self.layout_1)
        self.pushbutton1.setText("Enter name")
        self.pushbutton1.setGeometry(QRect(307, 180, 180, 30))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Script")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushbutton1.setFont(font)
        self.pushbutton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.pushbutton1.clicked.connect(self.gettext)

        #push button 2
        self.pushbutton2 = QPushButton(self.layout_1)
        self.pushbutton2.setText("Start")
        self.pushbutton2.setGeometry(QRect(307, 240, 75, 30))
        self.pushbutton2.setFont(font)
        self.pushbutton2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.pushbutton2.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)

        #push button 3
        self.pushbutton3 = QPushButton(self.layout_1)
        self.pushbutton3.setText("Exit")
        self.pushbutton3.setGeometry(QRect(407, 240, 75, 30))
        self.pushbutton3.setFont(font)
        self.pushbutton3.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.pushbutton3.clicked.connect(exit)

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.second_layout()
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.second_layout)
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def gettext(self):
        self.text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Enter your name","Your name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")

    def second_layout(self):
        self.layout_2 = QWidget()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.layout_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = App()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, 
                            QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, 
                            QInputDialog, QStackedLayout)
from PyQt5.uic   import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Plant those trees")

        self.first_layout()
        self.initUI()
    # +++    
    def initUI(self):
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.layout_1) 

    def first_layout(self):
        self.layout_1 = QWidget()

        #image
        self.image = QLabel(self.layout_1)
        self.image.setGeometry(QRect(0, -10, 781, 381))
#        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap("3957f79ab9264dc.jpg"))
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap("E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png"))

        #label
        self.label = QLabel(self.layout_1)
        self.label.setText("Plant those trees")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(180, 10, 591, 241))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Script")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;")

        #push button 1
        self.pushbutton1 = QPushButton(self.layout_1)
        self.pushbutton1.setText("Enter name")
        self.pushbutton1.setGeometry(QRect(307, 180, 180, 30))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Script")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushbutton1.setFont(font)
        self.pushbutton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.pushbutton1.clicked.connect(self.gettext)

        #push button 2
        self.pushbutton2 = QPushButton(self.layout_1)
        self.pushbutton2.setText("Start") 
        self.pushbutton2.setGeometry(QRect(307, 240, 75, 30))
        self.pushbutton2.setFont(font)
        self.pushbutton2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.pushbutton2.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)

        #push button 3
        self.pushbutton3 = QPushButton(self.layout_1)
        self.pushbutton3.setText("Exit")
        self.pushbutton3.setGeometry(QRect(407, 240, 75, 30))
        self.pushbutton3.setFont(font)
        self.pushbutton3.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.pushbutton3.clicked.connect(exit)

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
#        self.second_layout()
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.second_layout())
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def gettext(self):
        self.text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Enter your name","Your name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")

    def second_layout(self):
        self.layout_2 = QWidget()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('click my', self.layout_2) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.initUI)      # +++
        return self.pushButton

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = App()
    main.setGeometry(QRect(500, 100, 700, 400))
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]